# How can I stop the script conditionally?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

in `Mysql` How can I stop query(script) if a value is specific value?

(edited)

for example,

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE example(
       IN monday_date DATE
       OUT payslip_indication_id INT
    )
BEGIN
    
    IF weekday(monday_date) != 0 THEN SET payslip_indication_id = -1; 
    ELSE 
    SET payslip_indication_id = 1;
    END IF;


END
//  
DELIMITER ;
```

In this case, if given `monday_date` is Monday, continue the script, otherwise, `SET payslip_indication_id = -1` and stop the script.

==================================

I sorted this out with `SIGNAL`

FROM the link below

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-signal-resignal/

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: please show an example script so it is clearer what you mean

Comment: @ysth it says 8.0.23